# Javascript modules multiple instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually im just studying `JavaScript modules`. They are pretty easy but i got stuck in when it comes to multiple `instances` of single module
here is my code

```
var Mod = (function() {
    var ops;
    ops = function () {
        var Num;
        this.set = function (e) {
            Num = e;
            return this;
        };
        this.get = function() {
            return Num;   
        };
    };
    return new ops();
})();
```

but when i do

```
console.log(a = Mod.set(1));
console.log(b = Mod.set(2));
console.log(a.get());  // output 2 :'(
console.log(a == b);    // true :/
```

i cant understand why this is happening? may be because `Mod` anonymous function only call one time but now my question how Jquery `$` works?
as

```
a = $("div")
b = $("span")
console.log(a == b) // false
```

and how can i achieve this behavior with my Mod should i go for another programming technique? but i dont want to use `new` keyword thanks in advance!
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxho96p9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this is happening? may be because Mod anonymous function only call one time

Yes, you understand it right. You only have one instance, single object, so `a` is indeed just another name for `b`.

> but now my question how Jquery $ works?

jQuery constructs new instances properly (see the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L21)), by the way with `new` keyword which you don't want to use for some reason.

**UPD.** Here is one approach for correct instantiation:

```
var Mod = (function() {

    function ops(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    ops.prototype.get = function() {
        return this.value;
    };

    return {
        set: function(value) {
            return new ops(value);
        }
    };
})();

console.log(a = Mod.set(1));
console.log(b = Mod.set(2));
console.log(a.get());
console.log(a === b);
```

Comment: then how to achieve it here?

Comment: bcoz in jquery we dont use `new`

Comment: thanks for jquery code but still i cant figure out how i can use it here?

Comment: Can you describe what is intended usage of your code you want to have?

Comment: `a = Mod,set(1)` and `b = Mo.set(2)` should be different ;) this what i want